# How do I get controls on an NSPanel to look correct?

Tags: cocoa

If I have a HUD NSPanel that is black/transparent and I add some controls to it. How do I get the controls to look correct? ie be black/transparent instead of white/opaque?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to roll your own, Apple only provides the window.

However there are third party frameworks that have many of the standard controls:

- [BGHUDAppKit](https://github.com/binarygod/BGHUDAppKit)
- [BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/blog/2008/11/13/introducing-bwtoolkit/) (note: [BWToolkit no longer works with Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368878/xcode-4-and-bwtoolkit))

Comment: BGHUDAppKit is exactly what I need.

Comment: I'd come across BWToolkit, but not BGHUDAppKit before.  Thanks!