# Xcode 4 and BWToolKit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4, bwtoolkit

Can we use BWToolKit or any other IB plug-ins in Xcode 4?

My old project uses the BWToolKit and now I can't open it without Interface Builder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note (added Oct 26, 2011): This answer is somewhat outdated now. See comments.**

Xcode 4 (as of time of this writing) does not support IBPlugins at all.
You'll need to install Xcode 3 and its Interface Builder to edit nibs with IBPlugins.
(Be careful installing Xcode3 though, as it might overwrite your Xcode4 unwantedly)

So in short: use Xcode3's IB for editing IBPlugin-infected nibs and Xcode4 for al the rest.

To my knowledge there has not been a public announcement/statement gegarding IBPlugins and whether to still stick to them, or not. ast time I checked (day after Xcode4's release) documentation on IBPlugin still existed and I couldn't find any mark on deprecation (or strangely enough not even Xcode4 incompatibilities) either.

For more info, let me quote from Martin Pilkington's great Xcode4 review:

> **Loss of IBPlugins**:
>   For all the cool new
>   hotness in Xcode 4, there is one big
>   gaping hole in its functionality.
>   IBPlugins cannot be loaded and as such
>   any NIBs that rely on components from
>   them cannot be edited. They can be
>   compiled, but only if you have Xcode 3
>   and IB 3 still installed. This is a
>   major missing component, though it
>   isn't unexpected. A line has to be
>   drawn at some point in order to say
>   "this is the first version we'll ship"
>   and IBPlugins are likely one of the
>   things that didn't make the cut for
>   4.0. Of course the big issues with IBPlugins is they don't work with iOS.
>   My hope is that they're missing
>   because Apple is working on an
>   improved system and would rather leave
>   it out of 4.0 than ship a half
>   implemented solution. That said I hope
>   they don't completely replace the
>   IBPlugin system as it is incredibly
>   powerful and one of the nicest plugin
>   systems I've coded for.

**[Read full article](http://pilky.me/view/15#ib)**

Comment: That's Martin Pilkington, not Mark.

Comment: Update: You can now (as of 4.1 & 4.2) open nibs/xibs containing objects from third-party IB plugins. These objects show up as plain views or plain (blue-block) objects, but the specific inspector palettes are not available. This lets you at least edit the xibs and position views, establish actions/outlets, etc. but you have to do the rest in code or use Interface Builder 3.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi, thanks! Forgot to update my answer at the time of 4.1's release.

Comment: Sorry but I can't get it to open with Xcode 4.2.1 or 4.3. As soon as I try to open a .xib that contains BWToolkit objects xcode complains "The file "xyz.xib" has a dependency on an Interface Builder 3 plug-in." and that you need to "Locate Plug-in & Upgrade" but it doesn't accept the .ibplugin file. Any idea what to do next?

Answer (score 3):

From what I've read, existing plugins won't work, or will be very unstable.  The consensus on this seems to be that if you rely on plugins, stick with Xcode3 for the time being.

Comment: This isn't just the consensus, it's the actual statement from Apple. Xcode 4 does not support IBPlugins at all, nor have they expressed any interest in bringing this functionality back.

Comment: Joshua, do you have a link (or better: quote) of that statement? Must have missed it. But then again I'm not (yet) a paying ADC-member. And any remarks by Apple on what to stick to instead, other than writing all that cumbersome UI code by hand?

Comment: I don't have the link handy but it is a thread in their devforums, which are membership-required. The latest release notes also state the lack of support directly (sans elaboration in the forums). The workaround is implied: "do it in code."

Comment: Well, that sucks big. And kinda goes against the whole purpose of IB, i you can't add your own stuff to it.

Comment: This is the only mention of XCode plugins by an Apple employee that I have seen in the forums: "I'm not saying that IB plugins can't provide convenience, and enable new workflows. What I'm saying is that they're not required for providing customized controls for your apps." Not much. They are not saying anything against them at least.

Comment: The release notes are very clear: In 4.0, they weren't supported at all; in 4.1 (and now 4.2), you can at lest open and edit xibs containing objects from third-party IB plugins but there're no object-specific inspectors (the third-party objects are represented as generic blue-block objects and custom views). You have to do your customizing in code (vs. an inspector palette in IB). Only Apple knows what future versions will allow but don't hold your breath.

Answer (score 1):

The folder:
/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Interface Builder/Plug-ins/
has a bunch of '*.ibplugin's. Don't know what that means.

Comment: tried to put my own ibplugin there, didn't work:
Exception raised while decoding document objects - Could not instantiate class named SRRecorderControl